# Make span inside <a> tag unclickable

Tags: html, css

**I got this done by setting `cursor:default` on span**

I have something like this

```html
<a href="#">
clickable part
  <div>
    <span style="pointer-events: none;">
            I don't want to be clickable inside a tag
        </span>
  </div>
</a>
```

I tried with pointer events but it seems like it doesn't work maybe because of positioning?
Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: It must be clickable given the parent `<a>` wrapper is. You can't make it unclickable in isolation from the parent. Hope that makes sense

Comment: i.e. Put `pointer-events: none` on the `<a>`

Comment: It is working as expected, what is it you need? OR should I ask, do you need the `span` to be clicked or unclicked?

Comment: @bowlowl but i want rest of <a> to be clickable

Comment: @Manjuboyz span to be unclickable

Comment: Can’t you just move the not-clickable elements out of the a tag?

Answer (score 0):

#### I dont know what you're trying to do but this code should work, according to your question

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <a href="https://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">
                clickable part
              <div id ="test">
                <span >
                    I don't want to be clickable inside a tag
                </span>
              </div>
            </a>

            <script>
            document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
                // do things, and then
                return false;
            };
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by adding an `onclick` event handler for the anchor tag, then checking if the event's target is a `div`.

```js
document.querySelector("a").onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName == "DIV") {
    return false;
  }
};
```

```css
a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div {
  color: black;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com/">
clickable part
<div>I don't want to be clickable inside a tag</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Pointer-events`, `overflow` and a clickable pseudo over the part where you want to allow click only  might do. *For more specific shapes, there is a second pseudo that can be used to lay another clickable part , but that's about it and might not reflect your real situation. you may consider using javascript.*

```css
a,
a div,
a div span{
  pointer-events: none;/* kill the click */
  position: relative;
}

span {
  background: gray;/* see where i stand */
}

a {
  background:lightgray;
  overflow: hidden;/* hide any part of the pseudo overflowing */
  display:inline-block; /* not sure what you wanted here */
}

a span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  /* whatever, it has to overflow the top part of a */
  pointer-events: auto;/* make me be the only area where my parent a can catch a click */ 
}

a:hover {
  color: red;/* see hover effect, should only be triggered while hovering the pseudo */
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
clickable part
  <div>
    <span style="pointer-events: none;">
            I don't want to be clickable inside a tag
        </span>
  </div>
</a>
```